# Magento: How to point to main website from another website/store in the same shop

Tags: url, magento

I'm trying to figure out how to point the logo address to the main website and also how to point some links to the correct url and not url's withing the same store.

For the Logo:

I know that inside the header.phtml I can point the logo's url to any address I want to by doing this.

Change

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>"
```

To

```
<a href="http://domainname.com" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>"
```

but I'd like to know if there's a way to always point to the homepage without changing to the actual URL. The thing is that I have several websites/stores within the same shop and if an user accesses another site, the logo's URL will point to the store's address, not the homepage. for example.

this is what it points to on the homepage.

domainname.com/index.php/

this is what it points to from the other website/store within the same magento shop.

domainname.com/storename/index.php/

So once on another website/store it will never point back to the base url but like I said, I'm trying to avoid using the domain name in the header.phtml. if there is no other way around, I guess what will have to do.

Thanks,

**EDIT:** After a bit of reading around I found out that I can use the following to point to the base address.

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>
```

so it would go like this

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>"
```

This works but is there any other possible way besides this?

Ok I'll post this here as well since it's all part of the same subject and I don't want to open another question yet.

Besides this, I'm trying to have links in a static block (megamenu) link back to the main website in order to keep the structure of the site clean.

For example, I have this:

```
<a class="drop" href="{{store direct_url='shoes.html'}}">Shoes</a>
```

So if I'm in the main website the link on the menu would read like this.

```
domainname.com/index.php/shoes.html/
```

but if I go to another website/store within the same magento shop, lets say "Electronics" the link on the menu will change to this.

```
domainname.com/electronics/index.php/shoes.html/
```

but what I want is for the link on the menu to always domainname.com/index.php/shoes.html/ no matter what website/store I'm in. the reason is because I have two menus, one global and one store-specific menu and I can handle the website/store specific menu since it's a static block only visible to that store, so customers will not see that menu when they switch to another website/store but the global menu will always be visible and this global menu has ALL categories in it as opposed to the website/store specific menu which only shows the categories I want for that particular store.

uff, I hope I can be easily understood =/

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that if instead of using

```
href="{{store direct_url='shoes.html'}}"
I use
href="domainname.com/shoes.html/"
```

Only the top category will be linked to the main website from w/e website/store I'm in but the subcategories will will show as this.

```
domainname.com/electronics/index.php/shoes.html/
```

So that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

We use `<a href="{{store url='blah.html'}}">blah</a>` on our home page, which allows us to create tiles that link to products within each store.

So, in the `English store`, the code would link to `domain.com/us_en/blah.html`.
In the `Spanish store`, the code would like to `domain.com/us_sp/blah.html`.

There may be a similar link for website url, but we only have one website, so I have not used that.

Comment: Thanks for the response but using {{store url='blah.html'}} doesn't work when placed in header.phtml. that was my first approach since I use that too when trying to place a link on a CMS page. Also, if you have several websites in the same shop, using {{store url='blah.html'}} will keep you within the same store.